# Spawning process with arguments in node.js

Tags: node.js, process, spawn

I need to spawn a child process from `node.js`, whilst using `ulimit` to keep it from using to much memory.

Following the docs, it wasn't hard to get the basic spawn working: `child = spawn("coffee", ["app.coffee"])`.

However, doing what I do below just makes the spawn die silently.

```
child = spawn("ulimit", ["-m 65536;", "coffee app.coffee"])
```

If I would run `ulimit -m 65536; coffee app.coffee` - it works as intented.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 32):

Those are two different commands. Don't club them if you are using `spawn`. Use separate child processes.

```
 child1 = spawn('ulimit', ['-m', '65536']);
 child2 = spawn('coffee', ['app.coffee']);
```

If you are not interested in output stream(if you want just buffered output) you can use `exec`.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

child = exec('ulimit -m 65536; coffee app.coffee',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi vinayr. In your first example, does the `ulimit` really affect the following spawn/child then?

Comment: Ideally it should. Did you test?

Comment: Well, I did create a child script that creates a huge array with random data - eating up 220mb of ram according to `process.memoryUsage().rss` regardless of ulimit being used as in your example

Comment: Maybe you want to try 'ulimit -v' instead?

Comment: @vinayr: Is there anyway, where I could pass multiple parameters and create only one child process? This is what I am trying to do. var lighttpdObj = cp.spawn(lighttpdPath,['-f lighttpd.conf','-m lib']);

Comment: @VasanthSriram sure `cp.spawn(lighttpdPath,['-f','lighttpd.conf','-m','lib']);`